# pg_upgradecluster: dump or upgrade

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, upgrade, pg-upgrade

Why does pg_upgradecluster defaults to using dump/restore method instead of using pg_upgrade? The pg_upgrade method should be a lot faster than the dump/restore process. Is the upgrade method not safe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `pg_upgradecluster` and where does it come from?  It is not part of PostgreSQL.

Comment: It's kind of a proxy script that automates the cluster upgrade, either through dump/restore cycle or pg_upgrade.. I think it's only available on debian/ubuntu...

Comment: Maybe you should use an `ubuntu` or `debian` tag then...